# Meteor and Mongo AND tag filters with a twist

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Meteor application, where I have a mongo collection that has a tags field.

```
[{name: "ABC", tags: {"@Movie", "#free", "!R"}},
 {name: "DEF", tags: {"@Movie", "!PG"}},
 {name: "GHI", tags: {"@Sports", "#free"}}]
```

On my UI, there are three groups of checkboxes that are populated on the fly, based on the first letter of the tag name.

```
filter group 1: [ ]Movie [ ] Sports
filter group 2: [ ]free
filter group 3: [ ]PG [ ]R
```

The filter logic is the following:

- If filter group is empty then do not filter by that filter group
- If any checkbox from a filter group is checked, then apply that filter
- $and should be applied between filter groups (if movies and R checked, then only documents that have tags named "!Movie" and "#free" should be selected

I am struggling to build a mongo criteria parameters that follows the above logic. My code currently looks like spaghetti with lots of nested ifs (in pseudo code)

if (filter_group1 is empty) then if (filter_group2 is empty) then mongo_criteria= {_id: $in: $("input:checked", ".filtergroup1").map(function() {return this.value})}

What would be the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'm sure you mean that "tags" is actually an array since otherwise the structure would be invalid:

```
{ "name": "ABC", "tags": ["@Movie", "#free", "!R"]},
{ "name": "DEF", "tags": ["@Movie", "!PG"]},
{ "name": "GHI", "tags": ["@Sports", "#free"]}
```

It's a novel idea to store "tags" data this way, but it does seem that your program logic to construct a query needs to be aware that there are at least "three" possible conditions that need to be considered in an [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) combination.

In the simplest form where you only allowed **one** selection per filter group then you could get away with coming out to this with the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator. Just in simple MongoDB shell notation for brevity:

```
db.collection.find({ "tags": { "$all": [ "@Movie", "!R" ] } })
```

The problem there is that if you wanted multiple selections on a group, say the rating for example, then this would fail to get a result:

```
db.collection.find({ "tags": { "$all": [ "@Movie", "!R", "!PG" ] } })
```

No item in fact contains both those rating values so this would not be valid. So you would rather do this:

```
db.collection.find({ "$and": [
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "@Movie" ] } },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "!R", "!PG" ] } }
])
```

That would correctly match all Movies with ratings tags for "R" and "PG". Extending this for another group is basically pushing another array item to the `$and` expression:

```
db.collection.find({ "$and": [
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "@Movie" ] } },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "!R", "!PG" ] } },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "#free" ] }
])
```

Getting only the document which contains each of those "types" of filters to the matching value, so the "PG" movie is not free and "Sports" was filtered out by not adding to the selection.

The basics of constructing the query is working with an array of selection options for [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in each filter group. Of course then you only append to the `$and` array when there is a selection present in your filter group.

So start with a base `$and` like this:

```
var query = { "$and":[{}] };
```

And then add in each of the checked options in each filter group to its own in:

```
var inner = { "tags": { "$in": [] } };
inner.tags["$in"].push( item );
```

And then append to the base query:

```
query["$and"].push( inner );
```

Rinse and repeat for each item. And this is perfectly valid since the base query will just select everything unfiltered, and this is also valid without constructing additional logic:

```
db.collection.find({ "$and": [
    { },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "@Movie" ] } },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "!R", "!PG" ] } },
    { "tags": { "$in": [ "#free" ] }
])
```

So it really comes down to contruction of the query as MongoDB understands it. This is really just simple JavaScript array manipulation in building the data structure. Which is all MongoDB queries really are.

Comment: Great - that partially solves my problem of building the mongo criteria. I would still need to loop over all the filter categories and only insert criteria for those items that have at least one checked. Also, I am actually storing tags on a separate collection